# Put Gridview into PDF template, iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I'm attempting to use the code below to fill a PDF template with data from my webform. I want to know if it is possible to put a gridview into the form. Researching gives me mixed responses with some saying it can't be done and others that it can. I am not an experienced developer. Thanks in advance!

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells.Count);

            foreach (TableCell headerCell in GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                Font font = new Font();
                font.Color = new BaseColor(GridView2.HeaderStyle.ForeColor);

                PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerCell.Text, font));
                pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(GridView2.HeaderStyle.BackColor);
                pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);

            }

            foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in GridView2.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell tableCell in gridViewRow.Cells)
                {
                    Font font = new Font();
                    font.Color = new BaseColor(GridView2.RowStyle.ForeColor);

                    PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tableCell.Text));
                    pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(GridView2.RowStyle.BackColor);
                    pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
                }
            }

            string fileNameExisting = Server.MapPath("~/Invoices/Invoice_Template.pdf");
            string fileNameNew = Server.MapPath("~/Invoices/" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "_Invoice.pdf");

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileNameExisting);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(fileNameNew, FileMode.Create));
            AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            pdfFormFields.SetField("txtName", txtEmail.Text);
            **pdfFormFields.SetField("table", pdfTable);**

            string sTmp = "Invoice Generated for " + pdfFormFields.GetField("txtName");
            MessageBox.Show(sTmp, "Finished");

            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
            pdfStamper.Close();

        }
```

Comment: You do show your code but you don't mention how it fails. In which way does it not do what you want?

Comment: The line with ** around it is where the problem begins. This is basically wishful thinking on my part, it doesn't work. So far I can get values of textboxes or gridview columns to insert into my pdf template, I'd like to have a placeholder of some kind within my PDF template that would then take a gridview and display it.

Comment: *"This is basically wishful thinking on my part"* - Indeed, there is nothing like a table form field. Consider instead to have a text field where you want to put your table in your template. In your code you can then retrieve the coordinates and dimensions of the text field, remove the field, and add the table in place of the text field using a `ColumnText`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the text field to my PDF Template. Could you explain or show code on how to retrieve coordinates and dimensions?